# How to give names to MobX flows

Tags: mobx

How do I give a name to my flows?
I currently see messages in the console (using dev tools) like:

```
action '<unnamed flow> - runid: 3 - init' 
index.js:1 action '<unnamed flow> - runid: 3 - yield 0'
```

My code (in typescript):

```js
fetchMetricData = flow( function * (this: MetricDataStore) {
        const responseJson:IMetrics[] = yield Http.post("/metrics");
        this.metrics = responseJson;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to following text found in [MobX Api Reference · MobX](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/api.html#flow) page:

> Tip: it is recommended to give the generator function a name, this is the name that will show up in dev tools and such

Unfortunately, this is the only way to set the name (I use LiveScript and can't set names to function expressions while defining it).

In your case, you can turn your unnamed function expression into a named one. If you ever face another situation where you can't, you could also use `Object.defineProperty(myFunction, 'name', {value: 'myExplicitName'})`.

You can find the culprit in the code: [mobx/flow.ts at master · mobxjs/mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/blob/bf43367cd930a453af178ffcd236e0483bf876ee/src/v5/api/flow.ts#L21).